# i can´t see admob in my game

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

Good day, i try to see my admob but is not possible.
**THIS IS MY MAIN_ACTIVITY.JAVA**
        package net.canarolab.puzzleroad;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // private AdView adView;
    private MainView mainView;
    private final int MENU_SELECT_RESET = 1, MENU_SELECT_CONTACT = 2;

    // MUSICA
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;// para musica de fondo (se declara aqui para que
                            // pueda

    // utilizarla todos nuestros metodos)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // MUSIC
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.merry);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // Apago la barra de título
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Apago la barra de estado
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Activity Quiero solo tapa
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // View Establezca el
        mainView = new MainView(this);
        // setContentView(mainView);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // ADMOB
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

        // Create the adView
        // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e2f8fe3af5a6");

        // Add the adView to it
        layout1.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.setTesting(true);

        adView.loadAd(request);

        // Lookup R.layout.main

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_RESET, 0, "Reset");
        menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_CONTACT, 0, "Contact");
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // Leí el recuento juego
        this.mainView.gameCount.read();
        Log.d("", "read");
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();

        // Escribo el recuento de juego.
        this.mainView.gameCount.save();
        Log.d("", "save");

        super.onPause();
        // No voy a desaparecer en esta actitud no hay más.
        // finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        super.onDestroy();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_SELECT_RESET:
            this.mainView.gameCount.reset();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Has been reset．", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case MENU_SELECT_CONTACT:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "idea");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text of email");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { " trabajonacho33@gmail.com" });
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**this is my new new activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



</LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

     <net.canarolab.puzzleroad.MainView
           android:id="@+id/mainView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but admob is dificult for me .. and dont work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Activity:

```
  AdView adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
            AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
            re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE);
            adview.loadAd(re);
```

Xml:

```
<View 
        android:id="@+id/under_arrows_"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView1"
        android:background="#929091"/>

     <com.google.ads.AdView
         xmlns:ns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.adodis.taxmann"
         android:id="@+id/adView1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ns:adSize="BANNER"
         android:layout_above="@+id/last_update_Dated_text"
         ns:adUnitId="a14f98f978a08f1"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/last_update_Dated_text"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:background="#000000"
             android:paddingTop="5dp"
             android:paddingLeft="5dp"
             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
             android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Try This it will work sure

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="320"
    android:layout_height="50" >
```

adding this into AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Define this code in your activity_xml file.(Choose the place where you want
   to show your ad)

```
           <com.google.ads.AdView 

             android:id="@+id/adView"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 ads:adUnitId="a14e2f8fe3af5a6"
                 ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                 ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

2) Write this code in your MainActivity.java

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // This will request for new ads.

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());


   }
```

3) Define this code in manifest.xml

```
  <application>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

   </application>
```

Note: Make sure the package name of your project defined by you in ADMOB Dashboard is correct.

Comment: the principal problem is to mainView and adView in the same  activity_xml